# Coordinate Geometry - Area of a Quadrilateral

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadrilateral

What is the area in square units, of a quadrilateral whose vertices are $$(5,3), (6,-4), (-3,-2), (-4,7)?$$

I have tried creating the triangles, but didn't know how to find the diagonal. I wanted to try the shoelace method but I thought it only worked for triangles. The answer that was provided is $69$.

Comment: I drew the quadrilateral but I wasn't able to get the area of the 2 triangles it makes. I am not even sure if making 2 triangles is the best way to get the area of the quadrilateral.

Comment: You can definitely break it into two triangles.  If you want to do it that way I'd suggest using [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to find the area of each triangle.

Comment: But I don't know how to find the length of the diagonal.

Comment: The distance between two points $(a_1, a_2)$ and $(b_1, b_2)$ is given by $\sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2 + (a_2-b_2)^2}$.

Comment: I thought the distance between two points $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$ is given by $\sqrt{(a_2−a_1)^2 + (b_2−b_1)^2.}$ – ? Am I right?

Comment: You are not.  The Euclidean distance function $d$ between two vectors (though you can just think of these as points if you haven't seen vectors yet) $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is given by $d(\vec a,\vec b)$ $= \|\vec a - \vec b\|$ $= \|(a_1, a_2) - (b_1, b_2)\|$ $= \|(a_1-b_1, a_2-b_2)\|$ $= \sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2 + (a_2 - b_2)^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A(5,3), B(6,-4), C(-3,-2), D(-4,7)$.

The area of $\triangle ABC$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left|\vec{AB}\right|^2\left|\vec{AC}\right|^2-\left(\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AC}\right)^2}.$$
One can get the area of $\triangle{ACD}$ in the same way as above.

Added : Since $$\vec{AB}=(6-5,-4-3)=(1,-7)$$$$\vec{AC}=(-3-5,-2-3)=(-8-5)$$$$\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AC}=1\cdot(-8)+(-7)\cdot (-5)=27,$$one has
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left|\vec{AB}\right|^2\left|\vec{AC}\right|^2-\left(\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AC}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(1+(-7)^2)\cdot((-8)^2+(-5)^2)-27^2}.$$

Comment: How can i get the value of AC? AB=7, BC=9, CD=9,DA=7, AC=?

Comment: @Rubab: What does $AB=7$ mean? If you mean the distance between $A$ and $B$, then $AB=5\sqrt 2$, not $7$.

Comment: After I drew the shape, I saw that AB has |3|+|-4| as the length. How did you get the $5\sqrt2$?

Comment: @Rubab: $AB=\sqrt{(6-5)^2+(-4-3)^2}=\sqrt{1+49}=\sqrt{50}=5\sqrt 2$. By the way, my answer is about vectors. Do you know vectors?

Answer (score 4):

There's a neat method we can use in this case called the [shoelace formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) (which is derived from just adding triangles together, and is applicable in the case where we just have list of the coordinate points).

Application of this formula gives us that the area is

$$\begin{align}A&=\frac{1}{2}\left|x_1y_2+x_2y_3+x_3y_4+x_4y_1-x_2y_1-x_3y_2-x_4y_3-x_1y_4\right|
\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left|5\cdot(-4)+6\cdot(-2)+(-3)\cdot7+(-4)\cdot3-6\cdot3-(-3)\cdot(-4)-(-4)\cdot(-2)-5\cdot7\right|
\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left|-20-12-21-12-18-12-8-35\right|
\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left|-138\right|
\\&=69
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me about this method. I knew this method but I thought it only worked for triangles, not quadrilaterals.

Answer (score 3):

From the diagram:

$$11\times 10-\frac12 \times 9 \times 4 - 4 \times 1 - \frac12 \times 1 \times 7 -\frac12 \times 9 \times 2 - 2 \times 1 - \frac12 \times 1 \times 9$$  $$= 110-18-4 -3.5-9-2-4.5 =69$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. :) 1 Large Rectangle - 4 Triangle-2 Small Rectangle

Answer (score 1):

You want a really easy way to do this??  Check this out!

Given the four vertices: (5,3),(6,−4),(−3,−2),(−4,7), find the Area:

(1) Determine the diagonal "vectors" (by subtracting the opposite vertices):

```
d1 = (5, 3)  - (-3,-2)  =   (8, 5)

d2 = (6,-4) -  (-4, 7)  =   (10,-11)
```

(2) The area equals 1/2 of the absolute value of the "cross-product" of the diagonals:

```
X = 1/2 * | (8 * -11) - (10 * 5) | = 1/2 * 138 = 69.
```

This works for any irregular quadrilateral.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula
Area of Triangle = 1/2(x1(y2−y3)+x2(y3−y1)+x3(y1−y2)
Join the diagonal (any one) then find the area of two triangles formed by above formula

Comment: Please use mathjax

Answer (score -1):

A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2), C(x3,y3), D(x4,y4) are verticies of a quadrilateral either convex or concave (one of the internal angle greater than 180 degrees) taken in order,  then we can use the following elegant formula for calculating it's area.

A= 1/2*abs((xi-x3) *(y2-y4) -(x2-x4) *(y1-y3))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1329861)

Comment: @Jan Are you sure? Did you checked this formula?

Comment: This formula is derived from sum of two triangles formed by any of the diagonals. the points have to be taken in order, either clockwise or anticlockwise.